# Mongoose aggregation, how perform 'select as'?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have just started working with Mongo Db using Mongoose.js library.
I have two schemas, Orders and Payments.
I want to make a simple query to get all orders with property of sum of all payments for that order.

Schemas

Order

```
{ name : String }
```

Payment

```
{ date : Date, order : Schema.ObjectId, sum : Number }
```

In mysql I would do it this way:

```
select *,(select SUM(sum) from payments where payments.order = orders.id group by payments.order) as sum from orders
```

I was looking for aggregation methods to build the query. But all examples I have found is for the single object. I have no trouble to get the sum for single order (using findOne() and aggregation). But how I do it for array of orders?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with just one query in MongoDB with the schema design you have. Your schema is fine for a relational DB, but it might not be ideal for NoSQL.

With your schema you would have to do two queries:

- An aggregation job on payment to sum the payments grouped by order
- A a find(),or findOne(), on order to get the name of the order

An alternative schema would be to have just one collection of order documents and storing the payments as sub-documents on the order document, eg. an order would look something like this:

```
{ 
   name: "Foo"
   payments: [ { date: xxxx, sum: 42.00}, { date: yyyy, sum: 12.00} ]
}
```

Take a look at the Mongo documentation on data models for more: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/#data-models

Comment: Thanks, also I can hold a reference to Payment Object Id as array, but I also have to hold reference to Order inside payments. Simple to fetch objects with populate(), but each update I have to update both of schemas. If the payment has moved from order to order